# restore unset div width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a div  , I'm setting it's `width` to `650px` when I "minify" it, and I want to restore it's native `width` when I toggle my animation. My `animated_div` as you can see, has the `width` of the container , and only a `min-width` set. Here it is my code :

**HTML**

```
<div id="container> 
<div class="animated_div>
... 
<p>really a lot of text here</p>
...
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.animated_div{
 padding:20px;
 min-width:650px;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 margin-top:10px;
 }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#toggle_click").on('click', function() {
  $("#animated_div").animate({
  width : "650px"
 })

$("#toggle_click2").on('click', function() {
  $("#animated_div").animate({
  width : "100%"   // Here it is the problem , It set the div to be over-widthed.
 })
```

The problem, as I wrote in the comment, is that if i set `100%` the div get more width than the container.

Comment: I believe the thing you are looking for is to set `width: auto`. Do you have a jsfiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: I already tried with auto and it's not working

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the width to "auto" via jQuery.  Your call would look like this:

```
$("#toggle_click2").on('click', function(){
    $('#animated_div').animate({ width:'auto'});
});
```

Comment: We'll need to see some more complete CSS then, as auto should leave it up to the browser to render the width in whatever is appropriate for how it is displayed.  If it's absolutely positioned, it should wrap to fill content.  If it's static, it should fill the width of its container, etc.

Answer (score 0):

100% width + your 20px padding will make your div 40px wider than your container.

Try, instead of setting your width to 100%, set the width back to inherit:

```
$("#toggle_click2").on('click', function() {
    $("#animated_div").animate({
           width : "auto"
    });
});
```

Also, don't forget the closing brackets and semicolon.